# Whats wrong with my has_and_belongs_to_many relationships?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

**FIXED BY:**
changing model names to match rails naming conventions

I'm getting the following error when I try to join a skill to a user:

```
 irb(main):006:0> user.skills << skill
NameError: uninitialized constant Users::Skill
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_r
ecord/base.rb:1341:in `compute_type'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_r
ecord/reflection.rb:173:in `klass'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_r
ecord/associations/collection_association.rb:146:in `transaction'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_r
ecord/associations/collection_association.rb:124:in `concat'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_r
ecord/associations/collection_proxy.rb:118:in `<<'
        from (irb):6
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/comman
ds/console.rb:45:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/comman
ds/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
irb(main):007:0>
```

Here is my users.rb file:

```
class Users < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_and_belongs_to_many :skills

end
```

Here is my skills.rb file:

```
class Skills < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_and_belongs_to_many :users

end
```

And here is my schema.rb file:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20111214152402) do

  create_table "skills", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "description", :null => false
    t.string   "skill_name",  :null => false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "skills", ["user_id"], :name => "index_skills_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "skill_id"
    t.string   "first_name",   :limit => 25
    t.string   "last_name",    :limit => 50
    t.string   "email",                       :default => ""
    t.string   "password",     :limit => 40
    t.string   "location",     :limit => 100
    t.string   "status"
    t.text     "bio"
    t.string   "question1"
    t.string   "question2"
    t.string   "availability"
    t.string   "image"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["skill_id"], :name => "index_users_on_skill_id"

  create_table "users_skills", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "page_id"
  end

  add_index "users_skills", ["user_id", "page_id"], :name => "index_users_skills_on_user_id_and_page_id"

end
```

If you can help that'd be awesome! If you need to see other files let me know.

Comment: How'd you end up with pluralized model names? That can't be helping. In any case, a `habtm` relationship would want `skills << skill`--you wouldn't set a list of skills to a single skill, you'd add a skill. In this case I'd be nervous about the class naming, though. Could be wrong.

Comment: use the `collection<<(object, ...)` method that is generated by the has_and_belongs_to_many macro, so in your case it would be `user.skills << skill`

Comment: i tried `user.skills << skill` and still got an error

Comment: @Mike Can you try with standard Rails classnames, just in case? Might be easiest to set up a new project to sanity-check doing things the normal Rails way.

Comment: The naming convention fixed my problem. Now I have a problem with it trying to find 'skills_users' table not 'users_skills' any idea why this might be happening. I'm just going to migrate a new skills_users table and delete the users_skills I'm still curious about why I needed to do this though. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`user.skills` is an array so in order to add a skill, you need to do

`user.skills << skill`

Additionally, on your schema, I notice that your `user_skils` table contains wrong foreign key id. I believe they should be `user_id` and `skill_id`.

**Update**

Your `users` table also looks wrong. You do not need a skill_id in your users table. Similarly, you do not need user_id in your skills table.

This is a small diagram of how the tables and attributes should look like

```
users            skills_users         skills
id      ---->    user_id
                 skill_id        ---> id
```

**Update 2**

Your model name looks wrong. It is a convention in RoR to use singular model name. `Users` should be `User`. Similarly, for skills.

Answer (score 3):

I think, the problem is that the `skill` is an instance of Skill, while `user.skills` expects a collection.

`users.skills = [skill]` should work, but there are different ways of creating associations.

upd. Dave Newton is right. To add records to an association you should use `<<`